# PyQt5 accessing data from child widget to be printed on parent window

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I need help accessing the value from the function `userChosenDate()` in the `OpenSelectDateTimeWindow` widget. I need this value to be printed on a QLabel object `printCurrentDate` on my main window after `pushButtonConfirm` from my `OpenSelectDateTimeWindow` child widget is clicked. I have managed to print out the default selected date chosen from my calendar widget in the child widget, but I could not figure out how to let the text update itself after another date was chosen from my child widget.

The UIs for both the widget and the main window were generated from the QtDesigner with the codes untouched. These are the following codes that I have added to instantiate the UI.

Here is the code for the widget:

```
class OpenSelectDateTimeWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_SelectDateTime):
    # initialise GUI and window
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # when Back button is clicked, window is closed
        self.pushButtonBack.clicked.connect(self.close)
        # when Confirm button is clicked, return day chosen by the user (print date, followed by day)
        self.pushButtonConfirm.clicked.connect(self.userChosenDate)
        self.pushButtonConfirm.clicked.connect(self.close)

    # 2 functions to return selected date and time on the
    # MainWindow UI / New Window UI where stall's information
    # will be printed according to the user chosen date and time

    # this function is to return user chosen date from the calendarWidget widget
    def userChosenDate(self):
        self.date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toString("dd-MM-yyyy, dddd")
        print(self.date)  # for checking in terminal
        return self.date
```

This is the code for my main window.

```
class OpenMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setDateAndTimeButton.clicked.connect(self.DateTimeWindow)

    def DateTimeWindow(self):
        self.SelectDateTimeWindow = OpenSelectDateTimeWindow()
        # initialise GUI and window
        self.SelectDateTimeWindow.show()
        self.printCurrentDate.setText(self.SelectDateTimeWindow.userChosenDate())
        ################need help here###########################
        #while self.SelectDateTimeWindow.pushButtonConfirm.clicked():     
            #dateString = self.SelectDateTimeWindow.userChosenDate()
            #self.printCurrentDate.setText(dateString)
```

Comment: `data = self.SelectDateTimeWindow.userChosenDate()`

Comment: your help is greatly appreciated! however, this causes the date to be printed on the textLabel once the SelectDateTimeWindow is opened, and the date does not change after I click on the Confirm button of my window, which is what I want to achieve.

Comment: @luminoustan Change the `OpenSelectDateTimeWindow` so it inherits from `QDialog` (in Qt Designer as well as your code). Then you can do `self.SelectDateTimeWindow.exec()`, which will block until the user closes the dialog. You should also change the button connections to `self.pushButtonBack.clicked.connect(self.reject)` and `self.pushButtonConfirm.clicked.connect(self.accept)`. The `exec()` call returns a [Dialog Code](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#DialogCode-enum), which can be used to tell whether the user confirmed/accepted or not.

Comment: Alright I will give it a try, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that adding @pyqtSlot() above the function where I set the text will allow what I want to work. Although I will like if anyone can explain what @pyqtSlot() really does as I am not really familiar with it.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about this - it does not really solve your problem.

Comment: Hmm.. I managed to print it in the main window by creating this function

```
@pyqtSlot()
def ConfirmClicked(self):
   self.printCurrentDate.setText(self.SelectDateTimeWindow.userChosenDate())
self.printCurrentDate.adjustSize()
```
followed by replace this function with the last line in the DateTimeWindow function

Comment: pyqtSlot while stated as not being necessary is actually necessary if you do not want the occasional hidden issue from cropping up sometimes -- the key here is anything that uses a `.connect(functionname)` is implementing a Signal associated with the object in question and every Signal should be received by a Slot in order to prevent quirks from occurring.  So yes just implementing the proper `@pyqtSlot()` may actually be enough to fix some issue

Comment: But keep in mind it must be a proper `@pyqtSlot( )` which may mean it needs variable parameter(s) added to it such as `@pyqtSlot(int)` indicating this receives a Signal that has a integer value sent with it or `@pyqtSlot(str)` or `@pyqtSlot(object)` or `@pyqtSlot(int, str)` or etc...